# how to define multi primary keys and foreign keys in Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two tables in Mysql DB, it looks like this:

```
Table1:
   number  int  pk
   type    int  pk
   ...

Table2:
   number  int  pk fk
   type    int  pk fk
   ...
```

I defined models in models.py like this

```
def Table1:
   class Meta:
      unique-together = ('number', 'type'),
      index-together = ('number', 'type'),

   primary = ('number', 'type')   

   number = models.IntegerField()
   type = models.IntegerField()
   ...
```

When I migrate the model, The result isn't not what I want.

```
    BEGIN;
--
-- Create model Table1
--
CREATE TABLE "multiprimary_table1" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "number" integer NOT NULL, "type" integer NOT NULL);
--
-- Alter unique_together for table1 (1 constraint(s))
--
ALTER TABLE "multiprimary_table1" RENAME TO "multiprimary_table1__old";
CREATE TABLE "multiprimary_table1" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "number" integer NOT NULL, "type" integer NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO "multiprimary_table1" ("type", "id", "number") SELECT "type", "id", "number" FROM "multiprimary_table1__old";
DROP TABLE "multiprimary_table1__old";
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "multiprimary_table1_number_8d499fc9_uniq" ON "multiprimary_table1" ("number", "type");
--
-- Alter index_together for table1 (1 constraint(s))
--
ALTER TABLE "multiprimary_table1" RENAME TO "multiprimary_table1__old";
CREATE TABLE "multiprimary_table1" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "number" integer NOT NULL, "type" integer NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO "multiprimary_table1" ("type", "id", "number") SELECT "type", "id", "number" FROM "multiprimary_table1__old";
DROP TABLE "multiprimary_table1__old";
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "multiprimary_table1_number_8d499fc9_uniq" ON "multiprimary_table1" ("number", "type");
CREATE INDEX "multiprimary_table1_number_8d499fc9_idx" ON "multiprimary_table1" ("number", "type");

COMMIT;
```

Django add ID in my table and set primary key to ID column, How can I fix it?
And I don't know how to define multi foreign key either, could somebody tell me?

Comment: Django does not support composite keys. There was some work to add support, but I don't know the current status.

Answer (score -1):

Django Composite Key might be a solution for you:

https://github.com/simone/django-compositekey